# Mac OS X 1.9 Eclipse 3.4 line numbers don't scroll

Tags: eclipse, macos, osx-mavericks

I just saw that in my Eclipse 3.4.2 on Mavericks the line numbers no longer scroll. It also seems that the error markers are no longer displayed in the right pane (next to the code).

Has anyone else experienced the same? Is there a solution for this? I can't migrate to a newer Eclipse version at the moment due to some other graphical plugin libraries that I'm using.

Comment: On a quick test 3.4.2 barely works at all on my 10.9 system, You need to find a way to get to a newer version of Eclipse.

Comment: As noted above I can't use a newer Eclipse version just yet. This used to work with earlier versions of the MacOS and I thought that maybe there is an obscure fix for this. Eclipse is still usable it is just annoying.